# easymock throws assertionError with expectaction failed on verify

Tags: java, easymock

I've got this method that I want to test.

```
protected RestResponseStatus validate(INotificationValidator... validations) {
    RestResponseStatus resp = null;
    for (INotificationValidator validation : validations) {
        if (!validation.isValid()) { // <- need to test this
            resp = validation.createErrorResponseStatus();
            break;
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

In order to test it I created class and extended it with class with this method and create test method

```
@Test
public void nonValidBranchTest() {
    ParameterValidator validator = createMock(ParameterValidator.class);
    validator.isValid();
    expectLastCall().andReturn(false);
    replay(validator);

    this.validate(new ParameterValidator(TEST_STRING));
    verify(validator);

}
```

But when I try to run test - I've got an error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
   Expectation failure on verify:
     ParameterValidator.isValid(): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass the validator mock to the validate method?

```
ParameterValidator validator = createMock(ParameterValidator.class);
validator.isValid();
expectLastCall().andReturn(false);
replay(validator);

this.validate(validator);
verify(validator);
```

If you create a new `ParameterValidator` instance the mock will of course never be invoked.

As I understand... you want to test if the `validate` method invokes `isValid` on the validator and that in case it returns `false` the `validation.createErrorResponseStatus` is invoked.

Thus you should also record that behaviour

```
RestResponseStatus expectedRespStatus = createMock(RestResponseStatus.class);
ParameterValidator validator = createMock(ParameterValidator.class);
validator.isValid();
expectLastCall().andReturn(false);
validator.createErrorResponseStatus().andReturn(expectedRespStatus);
expectLastCall();
replay(validator);
replay(expectedRespStatus);

RestResponseStatus respStatus = this.validate(validator);
assertSame(expectedRespStatus, respStatus);
verify(validator);
```

Comment: Now I've got `Unexpected method call ParameterValidator.createErrorResponseStatus()`

Comment: Oh! I see. I thought I should only test one method call.

Comment: Now I've got `missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
ParameterValidator.createErrorResponseStatus()
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()`

So I should return for `createErrorResponseStatus` too?

Comment: Yes, it is because the method returns a RestResposneStatus and you have to say which object should be returned. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of your object to be tested in your test class, rather than extending it. Test classes usually don't extend the class under test, but rather mirror the package structure under src\main\test so you can access the protected methods.

The reason there are 0 calls is that you are calling `this.validate` which is executed on `MyClassTest` rather than `MyClass`